# SEO Tool for Amatuer SEO Professionals like me?

Tags: seo, seo-software

I have a management job now and I am handling 3 different websites' SEO. I mainly use http://4seohunt.com to track these :

- ALEXA RANK
- VISITORS PER DAY
- PAGE VIEWS PER DAY
- PAGE RANK
- FACEBOOK SHARES AND LIKES
- TWEET COUNT
- GOOGLE, YAHOO AND BING INDEXED PAGES
- GOOGLE, YAHOO AND BING BACKLINKS

Now I am realizing that this free tool I am using to look into each of the websites' statistics is not enough. I mean, it is useful, but not that reliable. I'd rather go to Alexa.com to check Alexa ranks, manually monitor SOCIAL MEDIA SIGNALS, and go into Google Yahoo and Bing Webmaster tools for Indexed Pages and Backlinks.

And it's an awful lot of work.

I am considering buying PRO at SEOMoz.

Is it worth it? The 100$ per month fee?

If not, what tools can you suggest that would let me do these primary things :

- GENERATE REPORTS (Visitors/day, Social Media, etc)
- Monitor Keyword Ranking and Site Page Rank
- MONITOR BACLINKS
- INSIGHTFUL KEYWORD RESEARCH

The websites are WORDPRESS based and has a YOAST SEO plugin and it's what I use for On-Page Optimization Monitoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to use the next tools:

- SEOquake (plugin for Chrome / FireFox). Probably, the best plug-in for SEO I have ever seen. You may configure it by yourself. It contains a great number of useful metrics for SEO.
- Alexa Traffic Rank (plugin for Chrome / FireFox). You don't need more to visit site alexa.com to see the most important ALEXA metrics. Try it too.
- MozBar (plugin for Chrome / FireFox). Great plug-in from SEOmoz. Free version allows you to see PA (page authority) and DA (domain authority), which is the most important from huge number of SEOmoz metrics.

For backlinks I can suggets ahrefs.com. Great service to research all due to backlinks of site (your or competitor). It is worth to buy PROFESSIONAL account ($79 per month or $790 per year).

To generate reports (visits, pageviews, likes, shares) use Google Analytics. It is great web-analytic free system for Google. Try it.

> I am considering buying PRO at SEOMoz.

Is it worth it? The 100$ per month fee?

I think it would enough for you to use Mozbar for free. If you will have some unique needs, you may try full version.

For keyword research, use Google Keyword Tool from Google Adwords account. It is for free. Also, you may try KeyCollector, but it is only commercial.

Answer (score 1):

SEOMOz has a free trial period of 30 days, however this is not enough to get a full picture of your websites. If you join Microsoft's [BizSpark Programme](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) (free to join), you get a SEOMoz 90 day trial period as part of the package. You will then be able to use it fully to see if it adds value to your role.

I am currently 40 days into the trial and it has been well worth it so far, but I don't see myself continuing after the 90 days as it's too expensive. They will be launching SEOMoz Light later in the year which will be cheaper, but I don't know what functionality it will have!